# I wont to diable windows 8 option in booting and directly start with ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-8

**First i have windows 8 and i was installed ubuntu 12.04 from windows 8. now when i start the system it shows screen with 2 os names for booting selection.
  But i wont to directly boot the ubuntu 12.04 withou showing select screen at the time of system startup
   Because my friends alwways pefer to windows 8 selction in booting time. Thats way i wont to hide the windows 8 selection when i start the system
plzzzz... help me**

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way to do is with grubcustomizer

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

You just install that app and I think you will get the hang of it, if not post here and I will show you how.

The harder way to do it is from terminal. See link [here.](http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/grub-2.html#mozTocId542243)